# How can I remove the page numbers and margin using context?

Tags: context, pandoc, markdown

I'm trying to use pandoc and context to convert a markdown file to a pdf.  The command I'm using is:

`pandoc -t context -o sample.pdf sample.md`

The sample markdown file I'm using is:

```
# Hello
* Trying to drop the page numbers
```

Which makes for a nice PDF, but has undesired page numbers at the top of the page.  How can I get rid of the page numbers (see top of screenshot)?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your self-answer works in principle but might render your document unportable, i.e. you might not be able to produce clean HTML output anymore.  I rather suggest you create a new file `preamble.tex` with the content

```
\setuppagenumbering[location=]
```

And then run `pandoc` with

```
pandoc -t context --include-in-header=preamble.tex -o sample.pdf sample.md
```

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out.  Was able to do with including commands into the markdown file like this:

```
\setupheader[state=empty]

\setuplayout [header=0pt]

# Hello
* Trying to drop the page numbers
```